# Avoid Aggregate 16MB Limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of about 1M documents. Each document has `internalNumber` property and I need to get all `internalNumber`s in my node.js code.

Previously I was using

```
db.docs.distinct("internalNumber")
```

or

```
collection.distinct('internalNumber', {}, {},(err, result) => { /* ... */ })
```

in Node.

But with the growth of the collection I started to get the error: `distinct is too big, 16m cap`.

Now I want to use aggregation. It consumes a lot of memory and it is slow, but it is OK since I need to do it only once at the script startup. I've tried following in Robo 3T GUI tool:

```
db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$internalNumber'} }]);
```

It works, and I wanted to use it in node.js code the following way:

```
collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$internalNumber'} }],
  (err, docs) => { /* ... * });
```

But in Node I get an error: `"MongoError: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB) at Function.MongoError.create"`.

Please help to overcome that limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the native driver differs from how the shell method is working by default in that the "shell" is actually returning a "cursor" object where the native driver needs this option "explicitly".

Without a "cursor", [`.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate) returns a single BSON document as an array of documents, so we turn it into a cursor to avoid the limitation:

```
let cursor = collection.aggregate(
  [{ "$group": { "_id": "$internalNumber" } }],
  { "cursor": { "batchSize": 500 } }
);

cursor.toArray((err,docs) => {
   // work with resuls
});
```

Then you can use regular methods like [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) to make the results a JavaScript array which on the 'client' does not share the same limitations, or other methods for iterating a ["cursor"](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Casbah users:

```
val pipeline = ...
collection.aggregate(pipeline, AggregationOptions(batchSize = 500, outputMode = AggregationOptions.CURSOR)
```